# Как сделать один marionette.controller для всех модулей

Tags: controller, router, marionette.js

Структура

```
|-app.js
|-controller.js
|-modules/
|--moduleA/
|---model.js
|---controller.js
|---view.js
|--moduleB/
|---model.js
|---controller.js
|---view.js
```

Хочется создать основной контроллер в controller.js, и там же подключать через define(requirejs) контроллеры модулей, они в свою очередь будут расширять этот контроллер, но что при этом делать с роутерами - не пойму.
Подскажите содержание файлов, нужен правильный и минимальный подход.

Answer (score 1):

Marionette.controller лучше не использовать. Это прямо говорится в документации: http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.2/marionette.controller.html

> Warning: deprecated. The Controller object is deprecated. Instead of
>   using the Controller class with the AppRouter, you should specify your
>   callbacks on a plain Javascript object.

В целом, в коде роутера можно с помощью require.js вызывать основной контроллер:

```
define(function(require){
    var Controller = require('controller')

    var AppRouter = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
        routes: {
            "": "index",
        },

        index: function(){
            Controller.some_method()
            this.navigate("index")
        }
    })
}
```

А в контроллере уже примерно тем же способом вызывать методы, объявленные в дочерних контроллерах:

```
define(function(require){
    var ModuleAController = require('modules/moduleA/controller'),
    ModuleBController = require('modules/moduleB/controller')

    var Controller = {
        some_method: function(){
            ModuleAController.some_A_method()
        },
        same_method: function(){
            ModuleBController.some_B_method()
        },
    }
    return Controller
}
```